# I want to store a function in variable and want to call that at onclick event

Tags: javascript

```js
var down_1 = document.getElementById('GFG_DOWN_1');
var fun = funto();

function funto() {
  down_1.innerHTML = 'From function 1';
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:green;">GeeksforGeeks</h1>
<p id="GFG_UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;"></p>
<button onclick="fun">click here</button>
<p id="GFG_DOWN_1" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
```

Comment: don't run `funto()` when you assign it to fun, instead set it equal to the (uncalled) function and then use `onclick='fun()'`

Comment: You don't need to store it in a variable in order to call it when the click event happens, just set it `onclick="funto()"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set variable to event, you can use `addEventListener` as

```
document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click',funto);
```

Your code `var fun = funto()` need change to `var fun = funto;`

```js
var down_1 = document.getElementById('GFG_DOWN_1');
var fun = funto;

function funto() {
  down_1.innerHTML = 'From function 1';
}

 document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click',funto);
```

```html
<h1 style="color:green;">GeeksforGeeks</h1>
<p id="GFG_UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;"></p>
<button id="click">click here</button>
<p id="GFG_DOWN_1" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to the community. 
Second, I would suggest you simplify your code. Instead of having variable outside function put them inside of it. Of course, if you ain't using them anywhere else.

So the JS code may look something like this:

```
 function fun() {
      document.getElementById('GFG_DOWN_1') = 'From function 1';
    }
```

and HTML, then, should look like this:

```
<h1 style="color:green;">GeeksforGeeks</h1>
<p id="GFG_UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;"></p>
<button onclick="fun();">click here</button>
<p id="GFG_DOWN_1" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
```

Please notice that you are calling a function in `onclick`, not a variable.